# actionlib and rqt

Tags: actionlib, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm learning ROS now and trying to create an action client in my rqt plugin.

No problem to catkin build the plugin.   But when load the plugin, I got error as below:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN9actionlib17ConnectionMonitor21cancelConnectCallbackERKN3ros25SingleSubscriberPublisherE)
```

Unmangled:

```
actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::cancelConnectCallback(ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher const&)
```

My code is similar to the following. Is it a rqt bug, or is there anything wrong in my code?

Thank you for your help!

```
class MyPlugin : public rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin
    {
      Q_OBJECT
    public:
      MyPlugin();
      virtual void initPlugin(qt_gui_cpp::PluginContext& context);
      virtual void shutdownPlugin();
    private
      Ui::MyPluginWidget ui_;
      QWidget* widget_;
    actionlib::SimpleActionClient<my_msgs::MyAction> aClient;
    }

MyPlugin::MypPlugin()
: rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin()
, widget_(0)
, aClient("some action")
{
setObjectName("Plugin");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271753/actionlib-and-rqt/) by [Fulin](https://answers.ros.org/users/683/fulin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-28**:
I've added the unmangled version of the missing symbol to your question text.

**Comment by [Fulin](https://answers.ros.org/users/683/fulin/) on 2017-09-29**:
Hi Gvdhoom,

By the way, where should I use

```
actionlib::ConnectionMonitor::cancelConnectCallback(ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher const&)
```

in shutdownPlugin()?

Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
That is a different issue, so I advise you to post that as a new question. We try to maintain a 1 question - 1 answer ratio here on ROS Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you linking all required libraries? Can you show your `CMakeLists.txt`? The fact that CMake currently does not complain is expected: plugins don't need all symbols present at compile time, as it is assumed that at runtime those will be resolved by the plugin host.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fulin](https://answers.ros.org/users/683/fulin/) on 2017-09-29**:
Hi Gvdhoom,

You are right,

I missed the actionlib related depends in CMakeLists.txt and package.xml files. Might be the boost also? After adding them, now it works fine.

Thank you!